# Facebook read_mailbox permission

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to make an android app that utilizes a persons facebook messages to do analysis and association with their fitness patterns (i.e. when have days where you talk to Johnny a lot you eat a ton of donuts sort of thing). However, after reading the facebook docs, it looks like I need the read_mailbox permission. It also looks like the read_mailbox will not be approved for any android/ios apps. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

There is a new `user_posts` permission that may be what you need. But you should create a prototype and send it in for review before putting too much effort into building the App. Afaik Facebook does not approve permissions for analytical Apps. You can also ask about that in the official developers group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/